# Can you use Windws 8.1 RTM to upgrade Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8, windows-8.1

Can you use the Windows 8.1 RTM iso to do a non-destructive upgrade to a current Windows 8 install?

How would one go about doing this if you can?

Comment: Of course you can. Proof: http://blogs.windows.com/windows/b/bloggingwindows/archive/2013/09/17/pricing-and-packaging-for-windows-8-1.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Wait 1 week until you see the 8.1 update offered in the Windows Store.

Comment: While true it does not answer the question beyond what has been posted already